# Ruby on Rails 'find' question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently using:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@posts = Post.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id = ?", @user.id])
@comments = Comment.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id = ?", @user.id])
```

Which identifies the user, and lists all their comments they've made.  However, I want to set a local variable for use in the _comment.html.erb template.  I want the variable to list the post's name located in the 'name' column of the post table.

I tried doing:

```
@post_id = @comments.post_id
@post_name = @post_id.name
```

But it showed an array error (because @comments lists the array of user comments). I need to find a way to be able to find the post_id for EACH comment.  Yet when I try using something like

```
@post_id = @comments.each.post_id
```

It shows an error because it doesn't recognise 'post_id' as a method. I want it to output whatever's in the post_id column for EACH comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going about this all wrong. The idea is to use associations so rails will provide accessors for you. You should only be using `find` to get your top-most record. Rails will populate the associations for you.

```
def User
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end

def Post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Your code then becomes:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])

# you can omit these and just use @user.posts and @user.comments in your view
@posts = @user.posts
@comments = @user.comments
```

If you want to output something for each comment, then use a loop in your view

```
<div class="comments">
  <% @user.posts.each do |p| %>
    <div class="post">
      <%= p.body %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: And to answer question itself, you can do "comment.post.name" in your template.

Comment: You can only do comment.post.name if you've set up the belongs_to and has_many associations.  Without that, even though the tables have post_id and user_id columns, they still won't know who or what they belong to unless told.

Comment: I can extract data from the 'user_id' column in the Post table, but I can't figure out how to then use that 'user_id' data to find data from the 'name' column in the User table.

The User table has an 'id' and a 'name' column; the 'id' column would be exactly the same as the 'user_id' column in the Post table.

Comment: @Jamie You're still not thinking about this correctly.  You don't have to *find* the username.  Just use `@user.post.name` or `@user.comment.name`.  Rails handles the rest. I suggest you read a Rails tutorial, because you don't know enough about how models work to be trying to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't issue queries yourself when you can leverage associations better.

If a user `has_many` posts, and a post `has_many` comments, you can simply do.

```
user.posts
```

and

```
post.comments
```

Also, it looks like a user `has_many` comments, so you can directly do

```
user.comments
```

To get the post id from a comment, make a comment `belongs_to` a post, then you can do:

```
comment.post.id # or comment.post.name directly
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class User
has_many :posts
end

class Post
belonds_to :user
has_many :comments
end

class Comment
belongs_to :post
end



<h1>users contriller</h1>
@user = User.includes(:posts).where(:id => params[:id]).first
<h1>in posts view</h1>
<div class="comments">
<% @user.posts.each do |p| %>
 <div class="post">
 <%= p.name %>
 </div>
 <% end %>
 </div>
 <h1>in comment view</h1>
 <div class="comments">
 <% @user.posts.each do |p| %>
  <div class="post">
 <%= p.comments.body %>
 </div>
 <% end %>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Post has many comments

and comment belongs to post. the should create the foreign key or the glue between post and comment.

remember that @user has all the post with the comment attached.

So to get to the comments id,go from @user.each.post({|post|

post.comment}